# how can I add a complete set of key:value pairs to an existing object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

how can I add a complete set of key:value pairs to an existing object in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using assign and adding an element to artists array, u can use push method , below snippet is attached, hope it may help ur question.

```js
let artists = [];
    artists.push({
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Tommy Gunzz1",
      "years": "1971 - 2020",
      "genre": "Web Design1",
      "nationality": "American Earthling",
      "bio": "Tommy Gunzz, formerly known as Tom Harris III, was born in Baltimore MD. Tom Harris was wisked away from his life to retreat to Alabama with His Mother, Mary Ella Vaughn Harris, Life would never be the Same!"
    });
    function addArtist(dataToAdd) {
       artists.push(dataToAdd);
      
    }

    var dataToAdd = {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Tommy Gunzz2",
      "years": "1971 - 2020",
      "genre": "Web Design",
      "nationality": "American Earthling",
      "bio": "Tommy Gunzz, formerly known as Tom Harris III, was born in Baltimore MD. Tom Harris was wisked away from his life to retreat to Alabama with His Mother, Mary Ella Vaughn Harris, Life would never be the Same!"
    };
    
    console.log("before adding",artists.length);
    addArtist(dataToAdd);
    console.log("after adding",artists.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Push to the array with your new data

```js
let artists = [{name: 'Artist1'}]; // Initial array of artist objects

function addArtist(newArtist) {
   artists.push(newArtist); // Pushing to the artists array
}

console.log(artists);

addArtist({name: 'Artist2'}); // Calling the addArtist

console.log(artists);
```